# How to add multiple audio and subtitle tracks to video?

Tags: linux, ffmpeg, video, subtitles

I'm trying to add an audio track and three subtitle tracks to a video file with already one audio track, but can't get it to work.  How does it work (on Linux in case it isn't obvious)?

The subtitle tracks are different language versions and it would be nice if I could add the appropriate metadata as [described here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71159290), while the two audio tracks are just renditions of the same thing in the same language, so the difference can only be described in human language.

Thanks!

Edit:

As per request of the first comment:
I tried many different commands, for example:

```
ffmpeg -i video_with_both_audio_tracks_already.mp4 -i subtitles_en.srt -metadata:s:s:0 language=eng -metadata:s:s:0 handler_name=English -metadata:s:s:0 title=English -map 0 -map 1 -c copy video_with_english_subtitles.mp4
```

which gives the following error:

```
[mp4 @ 0x56428f84ff00] Could not find tag for codec subrip in stream #3, codec not currently supported in container

[out#0/mp4 @ 0x56428f823540] Could not write header (incorrect codec parameters ?): Invalid argument
[sost#0:3/copy @ 0x56428f80f2c0] Error initializing output stream:
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add more details. How exactly are you trying this? Copy&paste the commands. In which way does it not work? Error message? Unexpected result?

Comment: Add `-c:s mov_text` after `-c copy`